# Crime Data in Canada

Tags: geospatial, government, city, crime, canada

Does anybody have any idea where I might find data regarding crime in Canada or whether or not this data even exists?

Comment: Sorry, but *crime in Canada* is just to unclear and broad. Please [read this](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-a-good-data-request-question-should-look-like) and [edit] your question. One tag would be [data-request]

Comment: I disagree with @JanDoggen (there's definitely a concept of crime data in the USA), and would suggest starting with the Canadian government, since they are the most likely to track crime data.